# Azure Data Factory Sink into CosmosDB All retries exhausted for 'REPLACE' operation

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a simple .csv file with three columns:

[image]

When we try to run the pipeline to import the data into the Cosmos DB via the Sink activity it fails with the following error:

> "Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'CosmosDB':
> {"innerErrorMessage":"All retries exhausted for 'REPLACE' bulk
> operation - statusCode=[412:0] itemId=[12345678_TEST],
> partitionKeyValue=[["SomeID.12345678_TEST"]]"}"

This started to happen out of the blue, no changes were made to the DataFlow. We also checked the data and it looks in the same format as before when it was not failing. The record exists in the database as well.

We are performing the update operation and are required to update the existing nodes with new Condition and Description values:

[image]

Question: **Any ideas what could cause this kind of error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears this happened due to there being duplicate rows in the .csv file. I guess, the bulk update operation cannot update the same node multiple times at such frequency.